# How does this circuit generate a high frequency signal?

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscilloscope, radio, high-frequency

I am new to electronics. I am watching [this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3I_e7gIyfQg&ab_channel=Afrotechmods)

At 5:37, you can see the first half of the circuit generate a high frequency signal.

How do an op-amp, 9 VDC, and a few resistors generate a high frequency signal?

[image]

Comment: You can simulate the circuit yourself by using this [quick online simulator](http://falstad.com/circuit/)

Comment: Are you familiar with astable multivibrators...?

Comment: @Dat:  The critical point is that there's a capacitor in the circuit.  Without the capacitor it is just an amplifier.  With an appropriately connected capacitor, an amplifier becomes an oscillator.

Comment: @JRE *Without the capacitor it is just an amplifier* You could say that but I'd still call it a **Schmitt trigger**.

Comment: @JRE ok, do you mean the 100p capacitor connected to the GND in the photo? I see the capacitor, but I don't know how they work.

Comment: You may wonder why the signal form is not rectangular like in texts which present how this type oscillator works or in the already given answer. Opamps have certain slowness which limit how sharp edged pulses can be generated. It's caused by the capacitors inside the opamp IC and parasitic capacitances inside the transistors of the opamp. The slowness is very obvious when the frequency is higher than a few kHz.

Comment: @user287001 yes, I see that in the video, the signal is sinusoid. But in the given answer, output singal is square wave form. Why is that?

Comment: It's only the time scale. The curves in the answer are drawn for so low frequency that the output looks rectangular. If the frequency was say 500kHz the output wouldn't reach and settle to the maximum before it should start to fall down. In math one could say the opamp attenuates the harmonics of the 500kHz rectangular pulses so much that only the fundamental is well visible in oscilloscope.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's called a [relaxation oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relaxation_oscillator): -

[image]

[image]

Wiki has a full explanation but, if in doubt, read [this](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa998/snoa998.pdf?ts=1626346825409&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fproduct%252FTLV7011) from TI entitled Relaxation oscillator circuit.

There is also [this page](https://circuitdigest.com/tutorial/relaxation-oscillator-using-op-amp) from Circuit digest should you need it. And also [this page](http://www.analogzoo.com/2015/01/relaxation-oscillator-design/) from Analogzoo.

Comment: These sentences from Analogzoo page: "When the op amp’s output is at Vcc (high), the positive input pin is held at 1/2 Vcc by the R2/R3 resistor divider. At this point, C1 begins charging up through resistor R1 until it too crosses the 1/2 Vcc mark. The op amp sees that its inverting input is more positive than its non-inverting input, at which point it drives its output to Vss (low)". I have a question: both input pins of the op apms are at 1/2 Vcc, why do the author say: "The op amp sees that its inverting input is more positive than its non-inverting input"?

Comment: Your quote says "until it too crosses the 1/2 Vcc mark" and that means the inverting input has risen slightly higher than the non-inverting input. I guess the word "too" is an error because the non-inverting input is held at Vcc/2 and doesn't cross it @Dat

Comment: Please help me more, also from Analogzoo page: "The problem is that resistor R1 and R4 (a required pull up resistor for the LM393 comparator) are both are connected to the comparator’s output pin, forming a voltage divider between Vcc and C1." What is pull up resistor? What is its role in the circuit? Where is Vcc? I can't see the voltage divider between Vcc and C1.

Comment: Stop please. I do not offer support to other people's web pages. A pull-up resistor can be googled. This is a Q and A site. You ask a question and someone provides an answer. Tutorials in the comment area are very restricted.