# Beginner nodal analysis exercise: Why would the voltage of the output of the op amp swing from 15V and 0V when op amp is in the follower configuration

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, ltspice, nodal-analysis

I wanted to analyze the function of this circuit.

When I simulate it the output of the op amp swings from 10 and 15V, but I can't seem to get there based on my analysis (by hand.)

Say we start off the circuit. V+ starts off with a voltage 0<V+<15V (but I don't know exactly what voltage would have been, in LTspice it would be 7.5V.) Then that voltage (V+) would force the output of the op amp to be the same, which triggers the charge to flow into the capacitor, until C1 reaches steady state, meaning that voltage Vout would be 15V. Now at node V+ voltage would be 10V (I am having trouble deriving that voltage using nodal analysis.) Now V+ is at 10V and V- at 15V.

Wouldn't the op amp sink current to have the voltage V- at 10V and Vo at 10V because it is in the follower configuration?

The capacitor discharges, then it would charge again to 15V, creating this swing of 15V and 10V.

The simulation says otherwise that the voltage output would be between 15 and 0, working more like a voltage comparator, and not a voltage follower (voltage between 15 and 10V.)

Also because I didn't understand why the node at V+ would be at 10V when Vout=15V.

I simulated that little portion. With nodal analysis I can't seem to get 10V.

[image: loop at v+]

[image: Total circuit]

[image: output signal of the circuit]

Comment: [Relaxation oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/575667/how-does-this-circuit-generate-a-high-frequency-signal/575668#575668)

Comment: For the also : you have R3 and R1 in parallel to 15V, and R2 to 0V, forming a voltage divider. Work it out yourself.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there is absolutely no follower configuration here. This is a follower:

[image]

It has 100% negative feedback. You could replace the feedback wire link with a resistor, and as long as there's nothing else connected to the inverting input, it would still be a follower.

Your circuit also has a capacitor connected to the inverting input, which may not have a huge effect, but is enough for me to say that it's no longer a follower.

Secondly, you have positive feedback too, which is due to resistor R3 modifying the potential of the non-inverting input, *in phase* with changes in the ouput. Not only is this not a follower, it's not even linear.

Let's examine two possible conditions that will illustrate the effect of this positive feedback via R3. Say the ouput starts at 0V. I'll redraw the net consiting of R1, R2 and R3 in a way that's easy to analyse intuitively:

[image]

As you can see on the left, since the right hand end of R3 is 0V (the opamp output), it is effectively connected in parallel with R2, the combined resistance being:

R1 ∥ R2 = R1 × R2 ÷ (R1 + R2) = 50kΩ

I've redrawn the net with R2 and R3 replaced with this single parallel eqivalent, on the right. I've also labelled the voltage at the junction of R1 and R2, which is:

Vj = 15V × 50kΩ ÷ (50kΩ + 100kΩ) = 5V

Now what happens when the opamp output is as high as it can be at +15V?

[image]

Similar calculations reveal that the voltage at that junction is now +10V, because R3 and R1 are effectively in parallel.

It should be clear, then that as the opamp output moves between the two extremes of 0V and +15V, the voltage Vj moves with it, between +5V, and +10V respectively. Vj doesn't change as fast, or as far, but it does change, and crucially it changes the opamp's non-inverting input voltage *in the same direction* as its output. This is what I mean by positive feedback.

Imagine driving a car. You constantly make steering corrections in an effort to *reduce* the difference between where you *are* going and where you *want* to be going. This is negative feedback, because the result is a *reduction* in the error, the "wrongness" of where you are going. Now imagine that you make changes in opposite direction, changes that increase that error. You crash very quickly. Your direction goes off track, and you make further adjustments to further increase that error, so you turn faster the wrong way, and so on until you crash.

It is only necessary for me to illustrate those two opamp output conditions (0v or 15V), because I know that positive feedback will cause this opamp's output to "crash", either at the top end of its range (+15V), or the bottom (0V). It will never settle at any other level in between, because even the slightest purturbation will send it flying to some extreme.

Now let's examine the effect of the resistor R4 and capacitor C1. The effect of these is to produce a voltage at their junction which changes slowly towards the opamp's output voltage. It creates a sort of delayed version of the opamp's output at that junction.

If the opamp output is +15V, C1 will slowly charge up, until it has 15V across it, and the junction of R4 and C1 is also +15V. When the opamp's output drops to 0V, the capacitor slowly discharges, until the voltage across it is zero, and the voltage at R4 and C1's junction is also 0V.

This delayed, slow slewing voltage is applied to the inverting input. The opamp will do with it what opamps do; amplify the difference between its inverting and non-inverting inputs.

As the inverting input voltage changes, at some point it will become equal to, and pass the voltage at the non-inverting input. At that point, positive feedback kicks in, causing the opamp output to crash to the opposite extreme.

Two things then happen. The non-inverting input changes potential as we've already discussed (if it was +5V before, it changes to +10V, and vice versa), and the capacitor voltage reverses direction of slew.

Again, eventually the inverting input reaches the same potential as the new non-inverting input potential, and another output transistion occurs, reversing the situation. This repeats forever, forming an oscillator. The output of the opamp is a square wave, between 0V and +15V.

R3, in combination with R1 and R2, effectively defines two "threshold" voltages, +5V and +10V in this case, and C1 and R4 provide a kind of "triangular" waveform, that, when it equals (intersects) the threshold, causes the system to flip its state. The flip is extreme and fast, due to the positive feedback afforded by R3.

Comment: BTW, what you've created is called a "relaxation oscillator".